# Проблема с запросом в mysql

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, какая разница между запросами: этим

```
select
  count(*)
from
  `drivers`
where
  `user_id` = 1
  and (`way1` = 25 or `way2` = 25 or `way3` = 25)
  and `travel_date`>1442682000
```

тут я отсчитал 10 последних строк в БД и из 11-той взял `travel_date`,
и этим

```
select
  count(*)
from
  `drivers`
where
  `user_id` = 1
  and (`way1` = 25 or `way2` = 25 or `way3` = 25)
order by `travel_date` desc limit 10
```

нужно выбрать count за последние 10 drivers (даты (travel_date) идут в по возрастанию). Первый запрос все выбирает правильно, но, дело в том, что он мне не подходит, т.к. для вычисления условия (`travel_date`>1442682000) нужно сильно заморочиться. Хотел переделать запрос без этого условия, получился второй вариант. Но он выдает неправильный ответ. Правильный ответ 3, а он выдает 181. Подскажите, почему так?

Comment: Потому что второй запрос сначала посчитает count(), а потом вернет 10 записей, а их там всего 1 после count() без группировки.

Comment: а возможно сделать чтоб count() посчитался после выбора 10 записей одним запросом?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, что тут count() считает, но можно так `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM travel_date LIMIT 10) AS tmp`

Comment: разобрался, спасибо огромное за помощь. Получилось так `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `drivers` where `user_id` = 1 order by `trawel_date` desc LIMIT 10) as tmp where (`way1` = 25 or `way2` = 25 or `way3` = 25 )`

Answer (score 1):

> какая разница между запросами

огромная.
второй запрос, к примеру, возвратит число, меньшее или равное десяти (даже если под перечисленные условия подпадёт больше десяти строк, директива `limit 10` возьмёт из них только десять, и результатом запроса будет число `10`).